# Coordinating system in console c++?

Tags: c++

I don't know wheres my error. It looks like I forgot the most basic stuff.

```
int xy [2];
cout << "Input X: ";
cin >> xy[0];
cout << "\nInput Y: ";
cin >> xy[1];
for ( int y = 0; y < 10; y++ )
{
    for ( int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        if ( x = xy[0] + 5 && y == xy[1] + 5)
        {
            cout << "°";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "+";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: What do you expect as output ?

Comment: output should just be 10 lines of + with one different char that would signify the position..

Comment: Did you intend to use assignment `if (x = xy[0] + 5...`?

Comment: there is no error, the console keeps drawing +'s

Comment: yes, i did intend to use the if (x = xy[0] + 5...

Comment: @user2744377 Please edit these comments on the intended output into your question; it is in danger of being put on hold for being unclear.

Comment: @user2744377: If you look at the _compiler_ output (Not MSVC's error window, the output window), It tells you the bug in your code: http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/BSv `testvc.cpp(15) : warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression`

Comment: What you forgot to do was [ask the question in a way we can answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) or post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) with output or compiler errors so we can assist you.

Answer (score 3):

May be you missed this :

```
if ( x == xy[0] + 5 && y == xy[1] + 5)
        ^ equality
```

which is why you're getting an infinite loop

`=` is an assignment operator , while `==` is used for check for equality

Putting `x= xy[0] + 5` actually assigns x to a value , rather than comparing hence never ending the inner loop

Comment: ? can you explain, all I see is that the loop is checking every coord if it a position ...

Answer (score 0):

Is this the output you wanted?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int xy [2];
  cout << "Input X: ";
  cin >> xy[0];
  cout << "\nInput Y: ";
  cin >> xy[1];
  for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++ )
  {
      for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
      {
        if (x == xy[0] + 5 && y == xy[1] + 5)
        {
            cout << "°";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "+";
        }
      }
      cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Executing the program....
$demo

```
Input X: 
Input Y: ++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should write this in line 10 (don't use the assignment operator):

```
if ( x == xy[0] + 5 && y == xy[1] + 5)
```

Comment: No problem. Could you please give an up vote if it worked, so that other users see the right answers?